# compatibility issues with regex between Mac and Linux machines

Tags: c++, linux, llvm

Original Question: "I developed a program on my Mac using Xcode 8's latest LLVM 8 compiler (clang 8/3.8?) which made heavy use of regular expressions out of c++14. I was then unable to get my code to give me the correct output when running on linux. There seem to be some regular expression compatibility issues that I am unaware of.

*How can I resolve this ?*

Comment: [gcc?](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier if you debugged the issue with the regex, share it back with us on SO (for an answer on how to fix), and then ultimately have your code even more compatible between compilers and operating systems? Or more bluntly, let's fix the bug in your code instead of changing the tool set. There is a good chance the issue is not related to the compiler per se, but either your code (i.e. bug) or a runtime library.

Comment: So, it dawned on me to 1) change the namespace for my regex usage from std:: to boost:: (and #include <boost/regex.hpp>). This fixed *most* of the compatibility issues. Then I discovered a bug in my code where I was advancing an iterator to a possibly null position of a vector and then trying to access it's memory. See my last post here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814019/segmentation-fault-with-boost-filesystem-on-linux-but-not-mac?noredirect=1#comment68848779_40814019> All is fixed!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question here.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, then you should *post an answer*, rather than editing the answer into the question! I see you have already posted an answer, so…it is rather unclear to me why you've also edited the answer into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap out std:: for boost:: like so

```
//using std::regex_replace;
using boost::regex_replace;
using boost::sregex_iterator;
//using std::sregex_iterator;  
//using std::smatch;
using boost::smatch;
//using std::regex;
using boost::regex;
```

and add

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
```

(I was already using boost::filesystem, so most of the headers/libraries were already included/linked). I guess it's not immediately apparent, but it should be noted that both of these features have more-stable parents in Boost (at least in the case of boost::filesystem, the 'experimental' version in C++ is actually just Boost).

So, that handled any compatibility issues because I was guaranteed to be following boost specifications on both my Mac and Linux machines.

Having this answer would've saved me 5 hours... Maybe now it'll save you 5 hours.